# Description of the helidon maven bundle flavors?

Tags: maven, helidon

Can anyone please help me understand the difference between the following helidon bundles on https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.helidon.microprofile.bundles?

1. Helidon Microprofile Full Bundle @ https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.helidon.microprofile.bundles/helidon-microprofile
2. Helidon Microprofile Core Bundle @ https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.helidon.microprofile.bundles/helidon-microprofile-core
3. Helidon Microprofile Bundles @ https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.helidon.microprofile.bundles/bundles-project

I am trying to go into each POM and seeing the differences, but it is too much of mix and match

Also, the latest helidon impl is version 3.2. I do not find it on the above URL. Is it available on a different location? Or one of the above three bundles points to the latest stable (3.2)?

Thanks in advance,
Rahul

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the doc at https://helidon.io/docs/latest/index.html#/mp/introduction/02_microprofile:

> The [full bundle helidon-microprofile] adds all the features available in MicroProfile.
> If you want to start with a smaller core set of features then you can
> use the core bundle instead. This bundle includes the base feature in
> MicroProfile (such as JAX-RS, CDI, JSON-P/B, and Config) and leaves
> out some of the additional features such as Metrics and Tracing. You
> can add those dependencies individually if you choose.

Briefly:

- `io.helidon.microprofile.bundles:helidon-microprofile` is everything
- `io.helidon.microprofile.bundles:helidon-microprofile-core` is pretty much the bare minimum to which you can add selective other artifacts as you need them

The latest Helidon release is 2.0.1 which supports MicroProfile 3.2.

Comment: Is the JPA (Eclipselink) too contained in the core itself?

Comment: No. Please take a look at this post Laird wrote https://medium.com/helidon/helidon-and-jpa-da20492f5395 that nicely describes adding JPA to a Helidon MP app. You can see the specific dependencies his example adds for the use case described in the article.

Comment: The guide (a more reference-oriented take) might help as well: https://helidon.io/docs/v2/#/mp/guides/09_jpa